# Trigger jQuery events one after another

Tags: javascript, jquery

Hi I am trying to create an animation where one class is added only after the one before it is finished triggered.

```
$('.flipper').click(function(){
  $('#first').addClass('first-flip');
  $('#second').addClass('second-flip');
  $('#fourth').addClass('fourth-flip');
});
```

so

```
$('#second').addClass('second-flip');
```

would only trigger when

```
$('#first').addClass('first-flip');
```

has finished its process.

so another way of explaining this would be.

Block A has a rotate effect added to it, after Block A is rotated, only then will Block B move 20 px right.

I basically just want to know how to create Jquery effects that trigger in sequential order.

Comment: this is a really cumbersome way of doing it, you could just have a flip class (unless each one has its own custom behaviour) and then use jquery animate and its completion block to fire the next animaton, alternatively use jquery queue to queue actions

Comment: https://api.jquery.com/queue/

Comment: Are you talking about wating for CSS transitions to complete? If so, you'll find answers if you search.

Answer (score 2):

You want to tie into `transitionend` or `animationend`. Here is an example using `transitionend`. After the box has finished moving, a new class is added which begins the next transition to turn the box blue.

```js
var mydiv = document.querySelector("#mydiv");

document.querySelector("button").addEventListener("click", buttonHandler);
mydiv.addEventListener("transitionend", onEndHandler)
  
function buttonHandler() {
  mydiv.classList.add("move-left");
}

function onEndHandler() {
  mydiv.classList.add("turn-blue");
}
```

```css
#mydiv {
  background: red;
  width: 10em;
  height: 10em;
  transition: 1s;
}

#mydiv.move-left {
  transform: translateX(100px);
}

#mydiv.turn-blue {
  background: blue;
}
```

```html
<div id="mydiv"></div>
<button>Move div</button>
```

If you need the jQuery version, it's here:

```
var mydiv = $("#mydiv");

$("button").on("click", buttonHandler);
mydiv.on("transitionend", onEndHandler)

function buttonHandler() {
  mydiv.addClass("move-left");
}

function onEndHandler() {
  mydiv.addClass("turn-blue");
}
```

Nice resource: https://davidwalsh.name/css-animation-callback

Comment: It's a fierce race out here.